# .change event is only fired the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Im trying to make a change event fire every time an file input in changed,
right now I'm trying to clear the value everytime and it worked the first time but when the the user change the file field the secound time the readURL(input) doesn't run.. why?

html

```
<input type='file' id="imgInp" onclick="readURL(input)" />
```

javascript

```
$("#imgInp").change(function(){
             readURL(this);
             ClearFileUpload();
    });   

function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      ClearFileUpload();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
      photo.innerHTML='<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="400" />';
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

       }
  }


function ClearFileUpload() {
     document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML="";
     var photo = document.getElementById('photo');
     var photoinput = document.getElementById('imgInp');
     if (photoinput != null) {
        document.getElementById('imgInp').outerHTML = photoinput.outerHTML;
    }
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="";
}
```

I've tried with .on('input') but this doesn't fire,

Answer (score 1):

You need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as you are changing the DOM:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('change','#imgInp',function(){
         readURL(this);
         ClearFileUpload();
});
```